# Backlight inverter failure on TI Travelmate

Tags: hardware, repair, lcd-display

I picked up a TI Travelmate 4000E for free and it worked perfectly using my AC adapter(genuine TI one from another 4000E). The backlight fires up full brightness for about a second, then dies. Inverter whines quite audibly while on, then stays quiet. LCD still works even with the BL out and using a bright flashlight shined into the display, the machine is usable.

So far, I can rule out both the CCFL tube and the LCD itself. I'm thinking maybe a recap of the inverter board, but that's just my best educated guess.

Comment: I'd look for a second/donor machine. It will simplify troubleshooting and give you a pool of additional spare parts for the future. If you swap boardsand it works, then your recap effort might result in two working systems.

Comment: If you're handy enough to do a recap, you might also consider replacing the inverter and CFL with LEDs instead.

Comment: I've already got a second one, a 25Mhz Passive Mono unit(this one is a 75mhz active matrix color unit). It works just fine, backlight is a bit dim but  quite usable under normal indoor lighting. Could always open that lid up and see if the inverter will swap in, but I'm not totally convinced. The inverter board between the mono,color, and active matrix I believe are different as all 3 use different controls to adjust display brightness(and contrast for the units with passive displays). And for LED modding it, I would prefer not to for the meanwhile if recapping is easier... Otherwise possibly.

Comment: If you need help on troubleshooting the inverter board, perhaps https://electornics.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask?

Comment: Recapped the board, it works fine now.

Comment: @Jason: Congrats for fixing your board, the usual suspect again ;-)